# Matlab: Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: string, matlab, prefix, cell-array

This code:

```
if (prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2)=='2')
    unique(prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,3))
end
```

returns this error:

> Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Why?

Comment: you might consider adding matlab as a tag in order to gain visibility to your question.

Comment: What do you expect the `if` statement to do?  `prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2)` looks like that it's a cell array, but your comparison doesn't make any sense at all.  In plain English, what is your `if` statement doing?  Take a step backward.

Comment: the error is specifically pointing to the part where you have `prefixTree2(:,2)=='2'`   Matlab does not allow `==` for cell comparing, and also '2' would indicate that it is a String type? Try removing the ' ' and see what error it throws?

Comment: I expect that if prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2) is equal to 2, the code find the unique values in prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,3). @GameOfThrone i have tried without '' but the code gives me the same error.

Comment: In which case, I think horchler has got the right answer, which uses `strcmp` the string compare function that can be applied to indexed cell and compare its content with another string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error implies that `prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2)` is a cell array. You can access the individual elements of the second column with `prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2{:,2}`. Also, the colon operator implies that there is more than one element in `prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2)` but you're trying to do a scalar comparison. Lastly, you're comparing to a `char` (`'2'` as opposed to the number `2`) and thus it would be best to use [string functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html). You can use [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html) to check each element of your cell:

```
prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2 = {'1' '2';'3' '2'}; % Example data
strcmp(prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2),'2')
```

Then use [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) or [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) to return a scalar for your `if` statement:

```
if all(strcmp(prefixTree(1,4).prefixTree2(:,2),'2'))
    ...
end
```